# How to insert onload="initialize()" class into the body tag for google maps

Tags: 7, google-maps

I am trying to display a simple 'hello world' Google Map on my page via the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).  I get it so far but what I'm cought up on is adding 
`<body onload="initialize()">` <strike>class</strike> attribute to my body tag.  What would be the right way to handle this?

Comment: Well, first of all, that's not a class, it is an attribute. Drupal 6 or 7?  Needed on every page or one particular page?

Comment: My apologies.  This is Drupal 7. And it was just on one page.  I found a functional answer to the question even though AFAK it doesn't actually add the attribute to `<body>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find my own answer.  This line doesn't necessarily add the attribute to the body tag, but it does call up the map.

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { initialize(); });','inline');
```